# Как отделить корни для системы нелинейных уравнений аналитическим методом

Tags: математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я хочу рисовать треугольники в Windows forms зная длины трех сторон. Для того, чтобы его нарисовать нужно три точки. Две из них есть: **(0,0)** и **(Длинна одной из сторон(l1), 0)**. Задача найти третью. Ее координаты есть пересечение двух окружностей: одна с центром **(0,0)** и радиусом **l2**(Длинна любой из оставшихся сторон), а вторая с центром в **(l1, 0)** и радиусом **l3**(Последняя сторона). Получим систему:

y^2 + x^2 = l2^2

y^2 + (x - l1)^2 = l3^2

У системы два корня, нужен с положительной ординатой. Я решаю ее методом Ньютона, но работает (разумеется) только с должным приближением к этому корню. А как найти приближение численно ума не приложу. Для одного НУ проще некуда, а для СНУ понятия не имею, прошу помощи в этом вопросе.

Comment: а где **l3**? *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: x^2 - x^2 + 2 x* l1 -l1^2 = l1^2 - l2^2 - отсюда x считается

Comment: Да, l3 добавил.

Comment: Меня интересует именно отделение корней

Answer (score 1):

Никаких приближений же не нужно. Перепишу с другими обозначениями, поскольку эти l* нечитабельны

Пусть длины а, b, c
Координаты (0,0), (a,0), (x,y)

```
x^2 + y^2 = b^2
(a-x)^2 + y^2 = c^2

y^2 = b^2 - x^2
(a-x)^2 + b^2 - x^2 = c^2
a^2 - 2ax + b^2 = c^2
x = (a^2 + b^2 - c^2) / 2a
y = + sqrt(b^2 - x^2)
```

Comment: Да, вы написали все правильно и возможно это самое эффективное решение моей задачи, но меня в процессе решения начал больше интересовать метод отделения корней.

Comment: Отделение корней имеет смысл, когда уравнение не имеет аналитического решения. В данном случае уравнение получается линейное, да и для квадратного нужно использовать аналитическое решение (формулу)

Comment: И это верно. Метод Ньютона для моей задачи слишком мощный и его применение здесь действительно лишнее, но меня интересует не сама  цель решить задачу, а конкретный способ ее решения.

Comment: Если в руках молоток, то всё вокруг похоже на гвозди ;) Придумайте задачу, где решение численными методам обосновано.